# Does Windows Server 2008 support NetBEUI ? If not - why not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

Does Windows Server 2008 support NetBeui ? If not - why not? ... pretty-much sums it up.

Reason I'm asking: wondering about an upgrade path for a proprietary system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN .. [No](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870909%28VS.85%29.aspx).

From the horses mouth ... the very first line
`Netbios is not supported on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and subsequent versions of the operating system`

and further on ..
`Windows XP and later:  NetBEUI is no longer be supported on Windows XP and later versions of Windows.`

Sorry ... perhaps you can run the app in a virtual instance of XP.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm aware of. The high level reason is because of Microsoft's push toward TCP\IP as the defacto networking protocol several OS versions ago. They officially ceased supporting NetBeui in Windows XP and subsequent Windows versions, although it was still possible to install it on WinXP and W2K3.